# Google algorithm for in-site search

Tags: javascript, api, search, google-search-api

I was wandering, does google provide a API or a widget for searching content into your website?

Something possibly that is possible to style or even better to plug via AJAX into a widget for realtime results.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well first off the have [Google Custom Search](http://www.google.com/cse/) which is always nice and it will search the content of your site for you. [From there you can get fancier and use the API to style it to a more custom manner of your choosing](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/docs/dev_guide.html).

Another alternative I've used a few times is [Lijit Search](http://www.lijit.com/). It will search and crawl all of your sites content for you. It isn't as customizable so to speak but has some nice features and looks nice by default and you can implement it quickly.

So if you have the time take a look at Google's Custom Search API, if you want something a bit lower level that still looks nice and takes less time lejit is also nice.

Comment: maybe i got it wrong but this Lijit link you postes looks like a advertising engine...

Comment: [Maybe this will help](http://i.imgur.com/04Eup.png)(I have lijit searching all these). It is an advertising engine and they advertise in the side bar like Google does on custom searches. It also shows breakdowns of who is looking at your website so you can know your user base(probably already do but it is another helpful analytic view). It provides a custom search for your site and the advertise in the side bar of the search results. You can join in and collect 50% of the money made from showing ads on your site. The search works well, the analytic breakdowns are ok and the ads keep it free.

Comment: Hwr, Google custom search is what i was looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can add `site:yoursite.com` to a search query.